# ODE with complex entires

Tags: c++, gsl, ode

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs with complex entries. From the GSL documentation it follows that it accepts only real entries. Is there any way to pass complex ones (anything more straightforward than distinguish real and imaginary parts)? In case it is impossible, could you please advise any other good library for this purpose?

Comment: A quick google turned up [this question](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gsl/2007-11/msg00006.html) on the gnu lists.

Comment: Splitting each equation into two, one of the real, one for the imaginary seems straightforward enough.

Comment: Thank you guys! I know this approach, but I wonder if there is any possibility to use pure complex variables?

Comment: If you already know this approach, put it in your question; it contributes to what is seen as *`research effort`*.

Comment: I did:

anything more straightforward than distinguish real and imaginary parts

But probably this was not clear enough. I am sorry for that, this is my first public forum post. I am sorry again for taking your time.

Comment: Sorry, my comment came across as harsh. I meant for you to make your question better by letting us know the avenues you'd explored. I didn't mean to imply you hadn't put any effort into your research, which is how it came across, rather to let us know about it. Welcome to Stack Overflow (c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [odeint](http://odeint.com). It ships with boost 1.53 and allows you directly to use complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I have just tried it and it seems to work as required.